# How to redirect .jpg to a wordpress post?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a wallpaper website and I recently checked the server log of the files accessed and I saw that I am getting lots of traffic on the image files rather than the page of the website.

So I want to do is redirect example.com/sample-image.jpg to example.com/sample-image.html

I am using WordPress CMS and I tried one .htaccess code but it redirects all the images to the homepage of website :(

Comment: If they access the page, then they access the images and a request for each one will show in the server log. You could look into preventing hotlinking.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.htaccess` redirects is a bad idea since it would redirect any JPG's you are using for example in your site design or the actual images used in posts. In effect breaking your entire site as you already have noticed.

There are many "solutions" (read dirty hacks) to prevent "hotlinking" images from other pages or web forums but in reality they most often do more harm in the form of blocking legitimate uses than good.

In most cases its a non issue. If the traffic is a problem than use a [content delivery network](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/CDN.html) for images on the page.

Comment: Most solutions to prevent hotlinking rely on things like http_referrer and CORS headers which do not work reliably across browsers. In this day and age when server resources are so plentiful and CDNs are even available for free it just something which you just have to learn to accept. The whole mindset behind trying to prevent it feels really 1998.